# Laravel 5.1 - Undefined variable in view

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have this controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.somesite.com/');
        $html->getElementsByTagName('article');
        $anc = $html->find('a');

        return view('welcome', compact($anc));
    }
}
```

and this view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                @foreach($anc as $item)
                    {{ $item }} <br>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Very simple and nothing special. just getting contents of a url and parsing it with a simple library and returning variable `anc` to the `welcome` view and then in the view i'm trying to echo each element. it gives me:

```
ErrorException in 051dd3929cf86b31dbaacb340018a3c5 line 9:
Undefined variable: anc (View: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)
```

Comment: I just tried `isset($anc))` and it's not set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `compact()` improperly. Correct usage is this:

```
return view('welcome', compact('anc'));
```

Pass the *names* of the variables you want compacted, as strings.

**PHP doc:**
http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Answer (score 1):

You are using the compact() function in your first block of code incorectly. Try this...

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
        {
            $html = file_get_html('http://www.somesite.com/');
            $html->getElementsByTagName('article');
            $anc = $html->find('a');

            return view('welcome', compact('anc'));
        }
 }
```

The compact function requires the name of the variable, not the variable itself.